# Mapping from java.time.MonthDay to java.sql.*

Tags: java, sql, datetime, java-8, java-time

We have a case, where we require only the day and the month and thus would use the `java.time.MonthDay` ([Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/MonthDay.html)) to represent that information.

We are aware that we could create our own JPA object for persistence or just use the `java.sql.Date` object, but that generally requires an unrequired year information. 
Another way is to call the method `.atYear(int)` ([Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/MonthDay.html#atYear-int-)) (with a fictitious year) on it and receive a `java.time.LocalDate` ([Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html)), which can be easily converted to `java.sql.Date`. But this is prone to missunderstandings in the future (and also persist the year information).

**Is there some "elegant"/supposed solution for this case? Or is there a replacement for SQL that supports the whole new date and time API for Persistence.**

Another case would be `java.time.YearMonth` ([Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html)).

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since SQL databases don't have a type compatible with [`MonthDay`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/MonthDay.html), use a `VARCHAR` columns, and simply use [`toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/MonthDay.html#toString--) and [`MonthDay.parse()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/MonthDay.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-).

Or use a custom [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html), if you don't like the `--12-03` format.

The default format will correctly sort, as a string.

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try and evaluate if this solution works for me!

Comment: This works perfectly as a replacement since in JPQL you still can use the comparison operators cause `String` implements `Comparable`

Answer (score 2):

here are the code snippets:

// column define:

```
@Column(name = "date", columnDefinition = "mediumint", nullable = false)
@Convert(converter = MonthDayIntegerAttributeConverter.class)
protected MonthDay date;
```

// converter define:

```
public class MonthDayIntegerAttributeConverter implements AttributeConverter<MonthDay, Integer> {

    @Override
    public Integer convertToDatabaseColumn(MonthDay attribute) {
        return (attribute.getMonthValue() * 100) + attribute.getDayOfMonth();
    }

    @Override
    public MonthDay convertToEntityAttribute(Integer dbData) {
        int month = dbData / 100;
        int day = dbData % 100;
        return MonthDay.of(month, day);
    }
}
```